# infopath custom page layout template

Tags: custom, form, template

I want to add a custom page layout template to my infopath form layout. Is it possible? 
actually i want to make my infopath desings on this background. 
thanks 4 help.

infopath 2013

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create a layout for infopath forms just like you would when creating a bespoke layout. The following links highlights who to create your own page layouts in Visual studio.

http://blog.beckybertram.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=71

The following highlights how to do it in SPD

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/create-a-new-page-layout-in-sharepoint-2010.html

If you want to Style the infopath forms then you need to do this in infopath and knowledge of HTML (using tables) will be required.

Hope this helps.

S

Comment: If this is the answer you needed can you mark this up. Regards,